# mktime forcing date to December 1969

Tags: php, date, mktime

I am having an interesting problem with the mktime function.  I looked at the solutions offered on here prior and none seemed to be resolved or helped (strotime doesn't change the results I see).

I have a monthly report that I am trying to make as error-proof as possible for my users, so I'm only requesting a month and a year.  I will provide the best day for the report in the code.

My form has a drop-down selection for the months, and the values for the month are two-digit integers (01, 02, etc).  The year is four-digit, filled out manually by the user.

Every works great up until the year 2038...  I know, I know, it's a long way off, but the project is supposed to have a 20-year scope and so in the last two years, I'm running into issues.

here's how I'm receiving the information from the form:

```
$month = filter_var($_POST["month"], FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
$year = filter_var($_POST["year"], FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
```

Then, I use mktime to combine the month and year with my day (27th):
    $timeStamp = mktime(0,0,0,$month,27,$year);

Then I assign it to a variable in a date form that MySQL likes:
    $reportdate = date('Y-m-j',$timeStamp);

I've echoed out the results of $month and $year and they are coming across correctly, but when I echo out $reportdate, it always says 12/31/1969.

```
03
2038
1969-12-31
```

It doesn't matter what month I choose.  December 2037 reports perfectly, anything beyond that fails.

Is this something that is fixable or am I just going to have to say that's the way the cookie crumbles...?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because your timestamp is overflowing, and is caused by the [year 2038 problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2038_problem).

Basically, integers are represented as signed 32-bits numbers, which can hold a maximum value of 2147483648. So, in a  UNIX timestamp, that is a certain amount in seconds, which is about 68 years.

In fact, Google tells me:

```
(2^31) * seconds = 68.0511039 years
```

So, UNIX timestamp is time since the UNIX epoch, Jan 1st 1970 00:00:00 UTC, meaning the largest date that can be represented in a 32-bit UNIX timestamp would have a year of:

```
1970 + ~68 = ~2038.
```

If you need to support these dates, use the [`DateTime`](http://php.net/datetime) class, as it does not have such a restriction, like so:

```
$date = new DateTime( "now", new DateTimeZone( 'America/New_York'));
$date->setDate( $year, $month, 27);
// $date->setTime( 0, 0, 0);
echo $date->format('Y-m-j');
```

Comment: Yep. Use an unsigned int instead of a signed one.

Comment: There's no such capability in PHP, as integers are internally represented as signed.

Comment: @Dancrumb - True, although it isn't much of an explanation, more of a note.

Comment: @nickb: totally agree - par for the course for PHP docs, sadly

Answer (score 0):

As explained above, you're hitting the 2038 problem with [`mktime`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mktime.php).

Luckily, it is fixable: don't use mktime. Just build your `$reportdate` value another way, that doesn't use `mktime`. Such as:

```
 $reportdate = $year."-".$month."-27";
```